# Symmetry group of the acyclic oriented L-cube using the Hyperoctahedral group

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, iteration, directed-graphs

I'm trying to figure out all elements of a symmetry group for the acyclic oriented $L$-cube. I do have an algorithm, but its complexity is not suitable for larger $L$. I computed $L=5$ on my old Laptop (took 30min, non-optimized code, single thread). I can imagine $L=6, 7$ or maybe $L=8$ is possible, higher once certainly not.

**First a bit of background**:
My main Question: How many different unique sets of $N$ maxima, which cannot be mapped onto each other by the [Hyperoctahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group), exist for the acyclic oriented $L$-cube? Those sets are called *peak patterns*.

- Acyclic means that there is no non-empty set of edges by which one can start at any vertices $v$, follow the arrow of the directed-edges and arrive again at $v$.
- Structure of the $L$-cube: Naming $2^L$ vertices by an integer value from $0$ to $2^L-1$. Two vertices are connected if their integer bit-strings have Hamming Distance $1$, see fig. below.
- A maxima/minima is a vertex with only in-/out-going edges. Two maxima have to have at least Hamming Distance $2$.
- Hyperoctahedral group: To put it simply, each bit-string vertex is transformed by combining two operations.
  a) Switching  $0$ to $L$ bits from $0 \to 1$ or $1 \to 0$, resulting in $2^L$ possibilities.
  b) Permuting the bit-string, resulting in $L!$ possibilities.
  Hence, the group has $2^L L!$ elements.

An example of two peak patterns can be seen here, including the corresponding transformation denoted by the arrows. (Also please ignore the numbers on the left plots, those are of no concern here) [image: fig. 1]
For $L=3$ and $L=4$, with $N=2$ and $N=4$ respectively, maxima are red. The upper case has $000$ fixed in both plots, while the lower one kept the same structure, but has relabeled vertices.
For $L=3$ there are $5$ peak patterns. $PP_1 = \{[000]\}$, $PP_2 = \{[000, 011], [000, 111]\}$, $PP_3 = \{[000, 011, 101]\}$ and $PP_4 = \{[000, 011, 101, 110]\}$. For $L=4$ I computed $20$ PP and for $L=5$ this algorithm found $287$, but I had no one to check my code so far.

**My algorithmic approach:**
Suppose I have a cube where each edge between two vertices is being directed to the edge with more $1$'s in their bit representation. This oriented $L$-cube is by construction acyclic. Placing $N \in [1, \dots ,2^{L-1}]$ maxima on the cubes, where ever and as long as possible, does not alter the acyclic behavior as only sinks (maxima) are added.
The peak patterns for N=$1$, $2$, $2^{L-1}-1$ and $2^{L-1}$ are possible to compute by hand:

- $N=1$: Just the $000..$ bit string, as each maxima can be mapped to it.
- $N=2$: Each "line" connecting two vertices of Hamming distance $2 \leq l \leq L$ can be mapped to another one of the same length. Therefore we have $L-1$ peak patterns.
- $N=2^{L-1}-1$: Only one possibility, but not needed for this post. (Note: Only for $L >= 4$)
- $N=2^{L-1}$: There is only one possibility, namely every second vertex being a maxima/minima.

Let all peak patterns with $N$ maxima be in the list ${PP}_N$
My approach to calculate the other peak patterns is iterative, by knowing the peak patterns for $N$, it is possible to calculate the peak patterns for $N+1$.
(Syntax is based on julia, although its just a scheme)

```
for pp in PP_N (A)
    for h1 in HyperoctahedralGroup (B)
        pp_possible = h1(pp) #apply the map h1 to each of the vertices in the set
        if all(HammingDistance(000..., possible_pp)) > 1 (C)
            Add 000... as maxima to the set possible_pp (D)
            for h2 in HyperoctahedralGroup (E)
                Check if h2(possible_pp) is already one of the sets in PP_(N+1). If yes, go to for loop B (F)
            end
            possible_pp is unknown, add to PP_(N+1) (G)
        end
    end
end
```

Motivation for the individual steps:

- (A) By removing any maxima of a peak pattern with $N+1$ maxima, the resulting peak pattern with $N$ maxima is a peak pattern already known. Hence start at unknown $N+1$ maxima peak patterns and get $N$ peak patterns, which are known.
- (B) Now apply all possible elements of the Hyperoctahedral group to the known peak pattern, to get all possible combinations.
- (C) Check if none of the vertices in the transformed peak pattern is the $000\dots$ vertex or vertex with only a single bit being $1$. This ensures that the $000\dots$ vertex can be added as a maxima.
- (D) Add $000\dots$ to get $N+1$ maxima which has been removed in (A)
- (E)+(F) Check if the newly created peak pattern is already known, if so go back to (B).
- (G) Peak pattern is unknown, add to list of $PP_{N+1}$.

**Now the problems regarding the heavily increasing complexity:**

- (A) Nothing to improve here I guess, as it's the heart of the algorithm, $O(|PP_N|)$
- (B) Has complexity $O(L! 2^L)$, but can be reduced by having the $000\dots$ vertex in each peak pattern set. Then only transformations with at least two bit flips are possible, resulting in $O(L! 2^{L-2})$.
- (C) Checking if one maxima has only $0$ or a single $1$ bit, $O(N+1)$
- (D) -
- (E) Again $O(L! 2^L)$, but due to the fact that each peak pattern in $PP_{N+1}$ has already $000\dots$ as a vertex, only bit flips which map any of the vertices in 'possible_pp' to $000\dots$ are possible. Hence, $2^L$ goes down to $N+1$.
- (F) Comparing each already known peak pattern in $PP_{N+1}$ to 'possible_pp', implementing it by just normal comparison: $O((N+1)^2 |PP_{N+1}|)$. When sorting 'possible_pp' and comparing it afterwards, the complexity is $O((N+1) \log(N+1) |PP_{N+1}|)$. [Using a hash function, is might be possible to reduce it to $O((N+1) |PP_{N+1}|)$, but this I haven't checked yet.]
- (G) -

The straight forward complexity to calculate $PP_{N+1}$ is $O(|PP_{N}| \cdot |PP_{N+1}| \cdot {(L! 2^L)}^2 \cdot (N+1)^3)$. Using my improvements it reduces to $O(|PP_{N}| \cdot |PP_{N+1}| \cdot L!^2 \cdot 2^{L-2} \log(N+1) \cdot  (N+1)^3)$. Note $O(|PP_{N+1}|)$ is not known at the beginning. 
But still, this is not suitable for larger $L$ I would like to compute. What really bothers me is the $L!$ complexity of permutations. Does someone has an idea for an improvement to some parts of the algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand your main question.  What do you mean by "how many unique sets of maxima exist for the L-cube"?  Does that mean, how many different orientations are there for the L-cube, where two orientations are considered different if there is no way to map the maxima of the first orientation to the maxima of the second orientation by some permutation in the Hyperoctahedral group?  I don't understand what "switching 0 to $L$ bits..." means, or your definition of the Hyperoctahedral group.

Comment: Your description is correct. By switching I mean that to my understanding the Hyperoctahedral group consists of two operations, either permuting bits, without changing their value and by switching from 0 to 1 and vice versa. The latter operation I referred to when I wrote "switching 0 to  bits...". The first few lines in the introduction of [this paper](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/86.pdf) describe it maybe more clearly. By e.g. switching two bits I mean $\bar{1}\bar{3}2$ transforms $010$ to $111$.